# Distribution of sample variance for non-normal random variable

Tags: distributions, estimation, variance

For a sample of size $n$ of non-normal random variables $x_1,...,x_n$. Is it possible to know which distribution the sample variance estimator follows?

Details: The distribution of $x_i$'s is not known. The only thing I know is that this $n$-dimensional sample was taken from a population with mean=0 and std=1. I also don't know about the distribution of the population.

thanks!

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $x_i$?

Comment: Hello, Juho! No, I don't know the distribution. The only thing I know is that this n-dimensional sample was taken from a population with mean=0 and std=1. I also don't know about the distribution of the population.

Comment: Basically, the answer is "no". What are you trying to achieve?